# How to automatically increment Code from the Database in Android?

Tags: android

I am using external database in my app and I want to get the maximum **report code (e.g. 13-T005)** from the database and increment it by 1. However I am struggling on how to get the last 3 digits since I use 'int' and it only get the last digit. How can I get the last 3 digits of the report code without having any problem with it or much better the whole report code itself? Thanks.

In my MainActivity.java:

```
    private void getNextReportCode() {
        tv_Code = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_Code);
        String query = "SELECT SUBSTR(MAX(ReportCode),5) AS ReportCode FROM " + Constants.TABLE_REPORT; //getting the last 3 digits from the code
        Cursor cursorReportCode = databaseHandler.getLastRCode(query);
        int reportCode = cursorReportCode.getInt(cursorReportCode.getColumnIndex(Constants.REPORT_CODE)) +1; //increment by 1
        String newReportCode = "13-T" + reportCode; 
        tv_Code.setText(newReportCode);
}
```

DatabaseHandler.java

```
    public Cursor getLastRCode(String query) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);  
            if (cursor != null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

        db.close();
        return cursor;
    }
```

Comment: Considered making `reportCode` a `String`, and using `cursorReportCode.getString(...)`?

Comment: @LuckyMe I actually did that solution but how can I increment it by using String?

Comment: Seems like a couple of other people beat me to the explanation :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code sample should do what you want.  The key is extracting your report index using substring since you mentioned it was in the last 3 digits.  Then you can parse and increment.  Getting it back to your report code requires a String format that uses "%03d" to specify a zero-filled int that is 3 digits long.

```
public class Report {

    public String incrementReportCode(String s) {
        // Get last 3 characters
        int length = s.length();
        String lastThreeChars = s.substring(length - 3, length);

        // Parse report index
        int reportIndex = Integer.parseInt(lastThreeChars);

        // Increment report index
        int incrementedReportIndex = reportIndex + 1;

        // Format as report code, with a zero-filled report index for the last 3 characters
        String reportCode = String.format("13-T%03d", incrementedReportIndex);
        return reportCode;
    }

}
```

Here is a test I made for this:

```
public void testIncrement() {
    Report r = new Report();
    String incrementedString = r.incrementReportCode("13-T005");
    assertEquals("13-T006", incrementedString);
}
```

Comment: how can I implement your codes using my codes above? I'm having a hard time in getting the report code from the database.

Comment: I think you get your report code in: cursorReportCode.getColumnIndex(Constants.REPORT_CODE).  Perhaps you can assign it to a String like: String reportCode = cursorReportCode.getString(cursorReportCode.getColumnIndex(Constants.REPORT_CODE));  You can then use this snippet to get the incremented report code: new Report().incrementReportCode(reportCode);

Answer (score 1):

Per LuckyMe's suggestion in the comments, you likely want to use a String.

Your question from there becomes: `How do I increment the String?` which seems to be equivalent to asking `How do I increment the number at the end of the String?`. (Correct me if I'm wrong?)

The key here is that you know that your Strings are going to follow a particular pattern; specifically, `[number1]-T[number2]` and you're interested in `number2`.

The tool that you likely want here is [Regular Expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). Fortunately, Java provides an API and a [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/). The gist is: you present the pattern that your String will follow, and the Regular Expression (aka Regex) lets you capture specific parts of it.

Hope that sets you on the right track!

EDIT: Specifically, here is [the Android documentation on regex](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/package-summary.html).